# Norator in series with inductor/capacitor

Tags: capacitor, inductor

I know that if I have a norator in series with a resistor, I can replace the resistor with a short circuit.

My question is, if I can do the same with a linear inductor/capacitor?

Comment: Huh?  What's a norator?  Also short circuit equivalent in what regard?  This question is lacking obvious necessary information such that it is impossible to tell what is being asked here.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Well, actually the question is, as it stands. What happens to a capacitor/inductor if I put it in series with a norator. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norator

Comment: Badly written question, won't add requested information.  Time to close and move on.

Comment: @OlinLathrop You could just tell me what you want to know. All I wanna know is what happens to a inductor/capacitor in series with a norator.

Comment: Should be closed!

Comment: Your question is not very clear but if you are just asking what happens when you plug a voltage/current source into an inductor/capacitor they are pretty standard interactions. I was going to write a comment as to why people where confused and decided it was easier just to answer your question and see if this is what you were looking for. Is my answer in general what you were wanting to know. The reason this is somewhat confusing is it seems many of us have never heard the term norator. I have seen the symbol, i just did not know the proper name it seems. I only use it as a currnet source/

Comment: Critical information like "what is a norator" belongs in the question, not the comments.  It's a made-up theoretical component, so its behavior is as you define it.  Let's try to stick to realistic components or models of real components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norator is an imaginary component, albeit you see if often used when you have a current source. You can only build one if it is functionally possible.

Let see, A current source driven into an inductor will start will a near infinite voltage as everything is turned on(not possible, but real inductors have a light capacitance or the real norator would not be able to drive infinite voltage) and over time would only have to output 0V to drive the current as an inductor goes to a short. A voltage norator would have to start driving zero current and slowly build up to need infinite voltage as the inductor becomes a short circuit. A real inductor has some resistance, a real voltage source cannot be perfectly ideal.

If you use a capacitor a current norator would have to constantly pump charge into the capacitor until it went to infinite voltage. This would either over-voltage the cap or fail the norator circuit, which as an ideal circuit really can only be treated as an ideal source as long as you stay within some specs. If used a voltage norator you would find it needed infinite current at first and would quickly decay to no current. If you do not pay attention to the first moment(which is limited by both your source resistance and capacitor resistance), just like the current norator with the inductor, you will find this is reasonable, capacitors are used on the output of voltage sources all the time.

Comment: Well yeah, I accepted your answer now, to reward you. You are probably right, that the norator is obviously not known well here. I think this is just not the right place to ask circuit theory questions. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @bamboon Circuit theory questions are perfectly fine here, but a purely theoretical component has no value at all unless you are using it to model something, but you haven't told us what you are modeling.

Comment: @Kellenjb it is part of a LL circuit we have analyse and find its phase portrait, however I thought that that is not important here as I wanted to know that more in a general way.

Comment: I am also not sure what an LL circuit is. Maybe you are just doing something that the nomenclature is different then what we are usually used to.

Comment: @bamboon, you will get some very useful advice here as far as circuits go, I have seen many well thought out amazing answers. I answered because I could not determine what you were wanting and the best way was to ask if this is what you are looking for. I do not know how you could physically be doing testing on a norator unless you had a "real" one. If you edit your question you will find that you receive much more interesting answers then mine.